# If non-array property exists convert it to one and push new value

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6, properties

Is there a simpler/shorter/better way to do this?

```
let obj={a:1,b:[1,2]}

function add(key,value){
  if(!obj[key].push){
    obj[key]=[obj[key]]
  }
  obj[key].push(value)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically after reading over the code, I interpret that the conditional (i.e. `!obj[key].push`) checks if the value at the given `key` is not an array. A more robust way to do that is to use (the negated value of) [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) instead. That may not be any shorter, but perhaps a better way to determine if the property at `key` is an array.

```js
var obj={a:1,b:[1,2]}

function add(key,value){
  if(!Array.isArray(obj[key])){
    obj[key]=[obj[key]]
  }
  obj[key].push(value)
}
add('a',3);
console.log(obj);
```

It would be difficult to prevent the re-assignment of the property `.push` (see example below). `.push` could be assigned to something other than a function, like an integer, string or object, or a function that does something other than push the supplied argument on the array.

```js
var obj={a:1,b:[1,2]}

function add(key,value){
  if(!obj[key].push){
    obj[key]=[obj[key]]
  }
  obj[key].push(value)
}
obj.b.push = undefined;
add('b',3);
console.log(obj);
```

#### Edit

[insertusernamehere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21444/insertusernamehere) made [a good point in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177090/if-non-array-property-exists-convert-it-to-one-and-push-new-value/177091#comment335994_177091): Perhaps it would be wise to guard against the case where the `obj[key]` is `undefined`. The current code would add that to the array, which is likely not preferable.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, including calling [`obj.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), checking the array returned by [`Object.keys(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) does [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) `key`, etc.

```js
var obj={a:1,b:[1,2]}

function add(key,value){
  if (!Object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      obj[key]=[];
  }
  if(!Array.isArray(obj[key])){
    obj[key]=[obj[key]]
  }
  obj[key].push(value)
}
add('a',3);
add('c',4);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I like your answer. I don't think that one should bother with possible reassignment of `push`, since a) it's an absolutely cornerstone method on arrays and messing with it _will_ lead to deadly daemons; b) the `add(...)` function depends on that heavily (a spread operator could be a work around instead of a push for inserts, but it's potentially much costlier, especially on large arrays). The only **"real"** question here is "how to reliably identify an array in JavaScript", IMO.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko so is what your saying that unless you use spread syntax this is probably the best way of doing it? And if you do use spread syntax their would be a definite performance penalty?

Comment: Yes, you read me correctly. `[...someArray, newValue]` will iterate over `someArray`'s values to produce a _new_ array. So it's by definition somewhat costlier. This may or may not be a big deal for you. Btw, I'm can't guarantee that `...` is not using `.push()` under the hood... And I can't see any problems in what you and Sam are having in your code snippets.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: The OP's and this solution don't test whether the key exists at all. If it doesn't, it will add an `undefined` value to the newly created array, for example when calling `add('x', 1)`.

Comment: Good call- perhaps we should add a check to ensure the key exists

Comment: yeah - I guess I have an aversion to it now because of a linter used on a project at work that complains whenever it finds calls to `.hasOwnProperty()` but that is simpler.

Comment: Do you use ESLint? They only advise to [call prototype functions like `.hasOwnProperty` on `Object` instead on the instance itself](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins).

Answer (score 3):

Another possible way is to use `concat` instead of `push`. You may still want to do a `hasOwnProperty` check to ensure the property exists.

```
function add(key,value) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key]=[];
  }

  obj[key] = [].concat(obj[key], value);
}
```